# What is elegant solution of conditional comparison?

Tags: c++

I want to sort vector of numbers in desend/ascend order, based of value of flag. Something like this:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers;
    bool is_negatif = false;
    // Do some stuff
    sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), is_negatif ? less<int>(): greater<int>());
}
```

Unfortunately such code will not be compiled because of different types of less/greaters structs.

I am using such code:

```
template<class _Ty>
struct MyComparator
{
   template <bool Less>
   static bool compare(const _Ty& _Left, const _Ty& _Right);

   template <>
   static bool compare<true>(const _Ty& _Left, const _Ty& _Right)
   {
      return _Left < _Right;
   }

   template <>
   static bool compare<false>(const _Ty& _Left, const _Ty& _Right)
   {
       return _Left > _Right;
   }
};
```

It is usage:

```
sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), is_negatif ? &MyComparator<int>::compare<true> : &MyComparator<int>::compare<false>);
```

What is elegant solution of such problem?

Note: bool value is not known at compile time!

Comment: `std::sort()` sorts in ascending order by default (using `std::less`).   Why not use that, and then use `std::reverse()` if descending order is required?

Comment: It will lead to extra performance

Comment: Why do you need the ternary operator? Just pass `is_negatif` as the template parameter.

Comment: You have measurements that support a claim the difference is significant?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall `is_negatif` is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: Do as Peter said, Sorting is O(nlog(n)) and reverse is O(n) so it will still be O(nlog(n))

Comment: @Peter, performance is not critical for in such case. Just it seems not so good solution for me

Comment: @Quentin, right, I completely missed the first code snippet for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: You could use a lambda expression.

Comment: `is_negatif ? std::function<bool(int,int)>(std::less<int>()) : std::greater<int>());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found another solution. It seems suitable for me. Of course, maybe there is more elegant solution

```
bool is_negatif = false;
// Do some stuff

std::function<bool(int, int)> func = less<int>();
if (!is_negatif)
    func = greater<int>();
sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), func);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you care about performance, then a single call to `std::sort` won't cut it. I just checked on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/jTXjfI) to be sure: both GCC and Clang generate assembly that loads either function pointer into a register, which is then used for each comparison in `std::sort`.
`std::function` is even worse because of type erasure.

```
movl    bool compareLess<int>(int const&, int const&), %ebp
// ...
movl    bool compareGreater<int>(int const&, int const&), %eax
// ...
call   [std::__introsort_loop specialized for bool (*)(int const&, int const&)]
```

If, however, you separate both specializations of `std::sort`:

```
if(is_negatif)
    sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::less<>{});
else
    sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::greater<>{});
```

You end up with two type-aware calls, in which the compiler can then inline the comparison.

```
call   [std::__introsort_loop specialized for std::less<void>]
// ...
call   [std::__introsort_loop specialized for std::greater<void>]
```

*(Crazy long specializations names abbreviated for clarity)*

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use something like this:

```
sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 
     is_negatif ? function<bool(int,int)>(less<int>()) :
                  greater<int>());
```

This, however, should have much worse performance than a plain `std::less<int>()` comparator, because this comparator will probably not be inlined.

Comparators that use `is_negatif` in the body are easier to inline but they will waste cycles checking `is_negatif` again and again.

If you want great performance, keep it simple:

```
if (is_negatif)
    sort (numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), less<int>());
else
    sort (numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), greater<int>());
```

Comment: I hardly think those cycles will be a major bottleneck.

Comment: @StoryTeller OP wanted something that will be faster than `sort(...); if (is_negatif) reverse(...);`

Comment: I though of same i.e using a simple `if(is_negatif){less}else{greater}`. But got confused in difference between what is code elegance and what is code readability.

Comment: But you can't really claim those cycles will make it **as** slow without profiling data.

Comment: @StoryTeller True but I can make an intelligent guess.

Comment: Regardless, I concur your last example will probably yield the *best* performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class T>
struct MyComparator
{
    MyComparator(bool __is_negatif)
    {
            m_is_negatif = __is_negatif;
    }
    bool operator()(const T& x, const T& y) const
    {
            if(m_is_negatif)
            {
                    return (x > y);
            }

            return (x < y);
    }
    private:
            bool m_is_negatif;
};


 vector<int> numbers;
 bool is_negatif = false;
 sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), MyComparator<int>(is_negatif));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to just wrap the whole thing in a lambda:

```
sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), [&](int l, int r) {
  return is_negatif ? l < r : l > r;
});
```

If you are worried about the conditional affecting performance too much, don't be. Any half decent branch predictor will figure out which comparison should be always called during the sort.

Answer (score 0):

how about a lambda?

```
bool ascending = false;
auto sorting_condition = [&](const int & a, const int & b) -> bool {
    if (ascending) return a > b;
    else return !(a < b);
}

sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), sorting_condition);
```

Comment: `!(a > b)` is equivalent to `a <= b`.    That comparison does not represent a strict weak ordering so does not meet requirements of `std::sort()`.